# Method annotation issue in Java 8u45

Tags: java, annotations

I have the following scenario.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ExampleAnnotation {}

public abstract class AbstractExample<T extends BeanInterface> {
    public abstract void exampleMethod(T bean);
}

public class ImplementationExample extends AbstractExample<BeanImplementation>{
  @Override
  @ExampleAnnotation
  public void exampleMethod(BeanImplementation bean) {          
  }
}
```

Where BeanImplementation is an implementation of BeanInterface.

If I compile the code using Java 8u45 and I list which methods of the `ImplementationExample` class have the annotation `ExampleAnnotation` using the following piece of code:

```
    Class<ImplementationExample> cls = ImplementationExample.class;
    List<Method> methods = new ArrayList<Method>();
    methods.addAll(Arrays.asList(cls.getDeclaredMethods()));

    for (Method method : methods) {
      System.out.println("method: " + method.getName() + " annotation: " + method.getAnnotation(ExampleAnnotation.class));
    }
```

Then I get that both these methods:

```
ImplementationExample.exampleMethod(BeanImplementation)
ImplementationExample.exampleMethod(BeanInterface)
```

If I use Java 7 or the Java 8 Eclipse Compiler then only the first method is annotated and this should be the correct behavior.

Is this a bug in the java 8 compiler? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What OS? I checked LinuxMint with Oracle java version "1.8.0_45" and only first method is annotated

Comment: @michaldo I am on Windows 7. After your comment I made the same test also on a LinuxMint machine as well using Java8u45 and again both methods are annotated. Are you maybe compiling and running the test using an IDE? As I wrote in my comment I don't experience any issues when I compile and run the code in Eclipse. Can you try to compile and run this example just using javac and java?

Comment: You are right, I made my test from Eclipse earlier. When I do it from command line I have the same results: Java8 see 2 methods annotated, Java7 1 method

Comment: I have submitted this as a bug to Oracle and if they reply I will update this thread.